# Using summarise alters the result of my computation

Tags: r

I have the following code, where I don't pipe through the `summarise`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

depArrDelay <- flights %>% 
  filter_at(vars(c("dep_delay", "arr_delay", "distance")), all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
  group_by(dep_delay, arr_delay)
```

Now doing 
`cor(depArrDelay$dep_delay, depArrDelay$arr_delay)`  yields `0.9148028` which is the correct value for my calculation

Now I add the `%>% summarise (...)` as seen below

```
depArrDelay <- flights %>% 
  filter_at(vars(c("dep_delay", "arr_delay", "distance")), all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
  group_by(dep_delay, arr_delay) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

Now doing: `cor(depArrDelay$dep_delay, depArrDelay$arr_delay)` yields `0.9260394`
So now the cov is altered. Why is this happening? From what I know, `summarise` should only through away all other columns that are not mentioned, and not alter value. Have I missed something, and how can I avoid that `summarise` alters the `cov`?

Comment: `summarise` will only yield one row per unique group combination, so the difference in the correlation is due to rows having the same values in `dep_delay` and `arr_delay`

Comment: If you look at your first `depArrDelay` it has 327346 rows and the second one has 20752, because the call to `summarise()` reduces each group (defined by a unique pair of values of `dep_delay` and `arr_delay`) to a single row. So since the first one is calculating the correlation over a different set of values with a lot of repeated values, and the other on a reduced subset with no repeats, you get slightly different results.

Comment: I see what you mean. Is there a way I can get the count without using the summarise?

Comment: You can try: `group_by(dep_delay, arr_delay) %>% mutate(count = n())`

Comment: That helped, thanks. Now it just takes forever to draw a ggplot because it has to look at all the columns, but at leat the cov is not altered

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, `summarise` reduces the number of rows. If you need the count without changing number of rows, you can use `add_count`.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

temp <- flights %>% 
      filter_at(vars(c(dep_delay, arr_delay, distance)), all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
      add_count(dep_delay, arr_delay)
```

If you then check for correlation you get the same value as earlier.

```
cor(temp$dep_delay, temp$arr_delay)
#[1] 0.9148027589
```

If there are more number of columns and you need only limited columns for your analysis, you can select relevant columns using `select`.

Comment: I already used the mutate(count = n()). It seems it does the same as add_count(dep_delay, arr_delay). But thanks

Comment: @States Yes, it does the same but without `group_by` and reducing one step.